# Python typing forward declaration

Tags: python-3.x, python-typing

I'm trying to write some code with generic types like this:

```
from typing import Sequence, TypeVar, Hashable, Protocol, NoReturn


class _SortHashable(Protocol, Hashable):
    def __lt__(self, other) -> bool:
        ...

    def __eq__(self, other) -> bool:
        ...


SortHashableT = TypeVar("SortHashableT", bound=_SortHashable)

def foo(sequence: Sequence[SortHashableT]) -> NoReturn:
    ...
```

For type hinting of `other` object, I tried following:

```
class _SortHashable(Protocol, Hashable):
    def __lt__(self, other: _SortHashable) -> bool:
        ...
```

But I guess that is not supported and my editor was flagging it as error. Is there a way to forward declare the type as it could be done in languages like C++? I am using Python 3.10 for this project.

Comment: From some quick testing, looks like my editor (VSCode) doesn't allow the hinted type to be the class that is being defined. Hinting at an already defined class works. Since type hinting isn't enforced, I tried putting the class in quotes like `"_SortHashable"` and my editor doesn't show an error anymore. It actually even colors the hint as a type.

Comment: Note that annotations have to be valid Python expressions at the time the line containing them is evaluated - so it is not "VSCode" which does not allow that: it is an inconsistent use with eager annotation evaluation (the default behaviod): the class is simply not defined at that point nevermind associated to its own name. Py 3.11 addresses this problem, however, forward references in general are still a problem.

Answer (score 3):

From Python 3.11 onwards you can use `typing.Self` for this case.

For previous versions, you can use the class name as a string - `"_SortHashable"` - in this case.

Pleas enote that [PEP 563](https://peps.python.org/pep-0563/) was created to address this, to the point there is a `from future import ...` group for allowing compiling all annotations as strings and explicit lazy evaluation later on.

But it turns out a lot of edge cases, and even whole use cases of annotations would not work, so [PEP 649](https://peps.python.org/pep-0649/) was creating to address these issues - but causing others.

The situation is currently unresolved, and there is no clear way forward as for the preparations of Python 3.12.

Comment: Thank you, @jsbueno. Yes, I did consider trying it as string but I didn't. Coming from C++ background, the string option didn't look elegant to me, not sure if mypy will even report an error if such contracts are broken. But it looks like that's the only choice I have now with Python 3.10.

Comment: the elegant solution is using the new `typing.Self` - if you are not using Python 3.11 see if there is any package implementing it in a backward compatilble way - (a mypy plug-iin, as it has no runtime effect)

Comment: `Self = TypeVar("Self", bound="_SortHashable")` seems a temporary WA as well.

Comment: @jsbueno for python below 3.11, there is `typing_extensions` package maintained by core team for such backports, which is officially advised for such cases.